# How to determine the most significant predictors - multivariate forecasting

Tags: r, forecasting, multivariate-time-series

I would like to create a forecasting model with time series in R. I have a target time series 'Sales' that I would like to forecast. I also have several time series that represent, for example, GDP or advertising spend. Unfortunately I have a lot of independent time series and I don't know how to figure out the most significant ones. It would be best to find out the most important ones already before building the model.
I have already worked with classification problems, here I have always used the Pearson correlation value. This is not possible with time series, right? How can I determine the correlation for time series and use the correlation to find suitable time series that describe my target time series?

I tried to use the corr.test() function in R, but I think thats not right.

Comment: Read [MCVE] and [ask]

Comment: Perhaps some useful reading: https://otexts.com/fpp3/selecting-predictors.html